# Limiting Android ArrayAdapter Results with Filter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to limit the number of results returned in a listview, which is using an arrayadapter to load strings into it.  I know that I can do this by overriding the getCount() method. The code below works at restricting results to a maximum of 15, however, when the filter is applied and the number of items being shown in the list view is less than the limit I set, the app crashes with an index out of bounds exception.  I have tried comparing the size of the results with no luck.  How do I limit the arrayadapter/listview to a maximum of 15 results while still displaying less than that when filtered?

**The Custom ArrayAdapter Class for override**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private int maxcount = 15;

  public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> results) {      
      super(context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.result_name, results);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount(){
      return maxcount;
  }

}
```

**The Filter in the Search Activity class**

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, resultsuggestions);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);       

inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
      SearchActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the minimum of `maxcount` and the number of items as count:

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
    return Math.min(maxcount, super.getCount());
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Was trying something like this, but doing it the wrong way.